# Code working in specific workbook but not in Personal Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook named Test and wrote a macros with the code below. It worked fine, but when I added it to my personal workbook, the code gave an error on line `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`.

> Subscript out of range.

I moved the code from a module to the Sheet1 on the Personal Workbook and then to the ThisWorkbook. Nothing helped. If you could give any sort of advice of what I could try that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("E1:E" & lastRow)

' filter and delete all but header row
With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*@*"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

' turn off the filters
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Did the code below work for you?

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") should work if you have a worksheet named "Sheet1" in the current workbook, were any of the worksheet names modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you specifically wish to refer to the sheet "Sheet1" in the currently open workbook?

If so, use the line below

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

And if you simply wish to refer to the current sheet, use

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

And if you wish to simply target the **first** sheet, whatever its name,

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

The way the code is currently written, it seems to be referring to "Sheet1" in the personal workbook and not necessarily the one currently active with the user.

Comment: I used Set ws= ActiveSheet and it worked thanks so much!